# Should I install fiberglass batts underneath my existing blown fiberglass?

Tags: insulation, attic, fiberglass

I have loose fill fiberglass insulation in my attic (picture below).  I was thinking about upgrading the insulation because, from what I've read, this is one of the least effective insulation types.

I was thinking about buying pink fiberglass rolls, clearing the loose fill out of the joist bays, putting the rolls down, then putting the loose fill back over top.

1) Is that a good strategy or should I be doing something else or using a different type of insulation?

2) If I buy the rolls, should I buy faced with a vapor barrier, or unfaced?  The loose fill currently has no vapor barrier.  It just sits on top of the drywall.

3) Is the cost of doing this really worth the difference in your energy bill?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever gave you the idea that blown fiberglass is substantially less effective than batts? Though the R-value of batts is 25-30% better, you simply account for that with increased depth.

The inadvertent gaps and voids that batts will leave you with after fitting around countless roof framing members surely negate any benefit versus simply adding more blown fiberglass. The only thing you should consider doing is increasing the depth, should it be inadequate.

Also, you can't simply move and replace the fiberglass. To be effective (and not clumped or matted) it needs to be blown in. That means hauling it down to a blower and cycling it through. Not worth it.

I'm in Minnesota (winters routinely to -30F) and blown fiberglass is by far the most common professionally-installed attic insulation. Cellulose is probably more common for homeowner jobs, but they're similar in the end.

Comment: FWIW, I was planning on adding attic flooring for storage.  Standing 2x8's on end on top of the joists and making a big platform.  I guess I can just fill those with even more loose fill fiberglass.  Thanks!

Comment: You want to be careful doing that. Standard trusses aren't designed for that weight. Putting concentrated loads in the middle strain the gusset connections as well as the bottom chords themselves.